# Can't change cell.backgroundColor in Editingstyle.Delete in swift

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

when the table is filled i can change the color of the cell with 
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

if i write it in editingstyle.delete it does nothing

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = toDoListarr[indexPath.row]

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(toDoListarr, forKey: "toDoList")

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

        toDoList.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try debug in commitEditingStyle function, debug is not here!

Remember, the selector commitEditingStyle is @optional in the protocol definition, so you don't have to implement it. However, UITableView knows that if you don't have it, why should it display anything that might cause an exception later in the code.

So you try change cell.backgroundColor in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath method!

Hope it to help you.